# cuda debian installation update-alternative error

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I have a nvidia graphics card and was able to install cuda in the past. Recently I reinstalled linux (ubuntu 12.04) and have been trying to install cuda using the debian package. I followed instructions from the Nvidia cudacast channel on Youtube(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVzSullC9l8) to install the cuda toolkit.

After I start with my `sudo-apt-get install cuda` I get the following error:

```
Setting up nvidia-current (319.37-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-server is already managed by x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-server (slave of x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf).
dpkg: error processing nvidia-current (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

It seems like this could be related to having a previous Nvidia driver that Ubuntu suggests installing by default. I tried uninstalling everything using the Software Center, but still no luck.

Any help?

Comment: Also the cuda-cast suggested trying /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall which I couldn't find either. The instructions in the cuda-cast match the ones here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html

Comment: To whoever down-voted the question, it would be helpful if you explained why. I could improve my question asking style that way.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming issues, not driver install issues. Your question is off topic. I didn't downvote but your question should be closed and i did vote to close. Use forums like superser or askubuntu instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem. There was still old Nvidia software installed, in spite of me uninstalling from the software center. I got rid of them using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

I then made sure that Ubuntu still had the desktop package

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I then restarted and installed the entire cuda toolkit using:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

That did it for me.